# Can I verify the password in a keytab file?

Tags: kerberos, ktpass

I have a Kerberos keytab file. Is there an easy way to verify that the password contained is the one that I assume? 
I looked at the file in a hex editor, and, according to the structure described at http://www.gnu.org/software/shishi/manual/html_node/The-Keytab-Binary-File-Format.html, the
keyblock types contained are 3 for des-cbc-md5, 1 for ??, 23 for arcfour-hmac-md5, 16 for des3-cbc-sha1, and 17 for ??

Comment: have you found the answer? I'm thinking of using ```kinit -k -t admin.keytab admin``` to verify whether this keytab works along with its username